# Conditional Destination View Controller from Sections in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios6, uistoryboardsegue

**Code in TableView Controller**

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showListFiles"]) {

    NSIndexPath *ip = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

    if (ip.section == 0) {
        NSDictionary *currentBill = [[_response objectForKey:@"facturas_pendientes"] objectAtIndex:ip.row];
        DkBPaymentViewController *pvc = [[DkBPaymentViewController alloc] init];
        pvc = (DkBPaymentViewController *) segue.destinationViewController;
        pvc.setUp = currentBill;
    }
    else if(ip.section == 1){
        DkBBillsFileTableViewController *ftvc = segue.destinationViewController;
        ftvc.filesList = [[[_response objectForKey:@"facturas_pagadas"] objectAtIndex:ip.row] objectForKey:@"archivos_facturas"];
    }

}
```

**Error**

```
-[DkBBillsFileTableViewController setSetUp:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x85a3b00
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[DkBBillsFileTableViewController setSetUp:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x85a3b00'
```

How can you do or what is the best way to conditional segue to different view controllers based on the section of the section of the table (Section 1 To pay / Section 2 Paid) ?

**Details**

DkbPaymentViewController has it's own xib given that I can't make the prototype cell to point to two different

DkBBillsFileTableViewController is the original segue that I declared

Thank you so much in advance, I believe that to find a good method of conditional segue in a tableview would benefit all.

Comment: Why don't you have 2 cells, and 2 segues, pointing to 2 different view controllers?

Comment: Thank you @wain if you add your answer I gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should setup 2 different cells, each linked to different segues (so they have different identifiers), and each pointing to different view controllers. This will make your code trivial, prevent confusion between classes and use segues as they are intended.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it programatically. In the storyboard, draw your two segues from the view controller (rather than from the cell). Then in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, do something like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SegueForSection1" sender:indexPath];
    } else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SegueForSection2" sender:indexPath];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, if my case was different im sure this would work!

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for! I accidentally let it autocomplete `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` for me at first, so be careful of that